# zsh: complete hostnames and files in given directory

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a script `myscript` which takes two arguments:

1. hostname
2. directory

How can I write my own zsh completion, so that whenever I do

---

```
mysript <TAB>
```

it completes from my hosts list (ie same as `ssh` does) and when I do

---

```
mysript host1 <TAB>
```

it completes from directories in `/home/martin/test/` ?

---

Comment: You might take a look at [This](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the interesting question. I would like to do the same in my  scripts. The [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html) is dense and not so easy to understand; I have not yet learned to work without actual options in the script. Here's my first attempt at accomplishing the goal with actual options.

First, I created a shell script named `myscript.sh` that uses options.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
self=$(basename "$0")
hflag=0 # Boolean: hflag is not yet detected
dflag=0 # Boolean: dflag is not yet detected

function usage() {
    echo "Usage: $self [ -h <hostname> | -d <directory> ]"
}

# If no options were given, exit with message and code.
if (($# == 0)); then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

# Process options and option arguments.
while getopts ":h:d:" option; do
    case "${option}" in
        h ) hflag=1 # The h option was used.
            host=${OPTARG} # The argument to the h option.
            ;;
        d ) dflag=1 # The d option was used.
            dir=${OPTARG} # The argument to the d option.
            ;;
        \?) # An invalid option was detected.
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
        : ) # An option was given without an option argument.
            echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG requires an argument" 1>&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

# One of hflag or dflag was missing.
if [ $hflag -eq 0 ] || [ $dflag -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

# Do something with $host and $dir.
# This is where the actions of your current script should be placed.
# Here, I am just printing them.
echo "$host"
echo "$dir"

# Unset variables used in the script.
unset self
unset hflag
unset dflag
```

Next, I determined where `zsh` looks for autocomplete files.

```
print -rl -- $fpath
```

I chose one of the directories, `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` in my case. The filenames that are considered autocomplete files begin with an underscore <kbd>_</kbd> character. I created the file, `_myscript`, in the directory. The portion after `#compdef` is the actual script name, above.

```
#compdef myscript.sh

_myscript() {
    _arguments '-h[host]:hosts:_hosts' '-d[directory]:directories:_directories'
}

_myscript "$@"
```

I then executed `compinit` to pick up the new autocomplete definition provided by the `_myscript` file. The result is that I can now use tab completion to specify a host after the `-h` option and a directory after the `-d` option while still maintaining some sanity in the parsing of options and option arguments in the script itself. The tab completion  presents available options even before invoking `myscript.sh` as well as making option order irrelevant.

Usage becomes something like the following.

```
myscript.sh -h <TAB> -d ~/test/<TAB>
```

---

### Summary Solution

On the second attempt, I created a simple shell script, `zscript.sh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

And I created a file, `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_zscript`.

```
#compdef zscript.sh

_zscript() {
    _arguments '1: :->hostname' '2: :->directory'
    case $state in
    hostname)
        _hosts
    ;;
    directory)
        _directories -W $HOME/test/
    ;;
    esac
}
```

I executed `compinit`.

Comment: thank you, that works. Although not exactly as I imagined. First, as I explained, I need to complete directories form specific path, regardless what my `$PWD` is currently. Wherever I am in my filesystem tree, I need completion to complete directories from `/foo/bar/`. Second, is it possible to get rid of the `-h` and `-d` switches ? First argument should always be host, second always directory.

Comment: completing hosts works. But completing the contents of `$HOME/test/` does not work. When I press TAB, it simply completes `$HOME/test/` path itself and then offers me files in current path. Also, not sure what you mean with `-P` vs `-W`. I need to complete the contents of  `$HOME/test/`, not the whole path. If it contains dirs aa1 and aaa2, then tab should offer those two.

Comment: perfect. Now it works. thaanks.

Comment: @Christopher - what should I use instead of `_directories -W`, when I want to complete only files in given path, instead of directories?

Comment: @400theCat Sorry for late response. I see you got the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665578/zsh-completion-only-complete-files-in-give-path-not-directories